# Upgrading Ubuntu 11.04 on Alienware computer

Tags: upgrade, 11.04

I have an old Alienware computer that I found in storage. It has Ubuntu 11.04 installed on it and I really would like to update to the most recent Ubuntu.  I am not Computer savvy when it comes to terminals and commands.  I don't know what to do.  All I want is to have my son able to watch Youtube but Flash won't install.  Nothing will install, I keep getting Fetch errors or failed to fetch.  I can't download Chrome website, because it says check Internet... Internet is fine. I don't understand what is going on or how to fix it?

Comment: Please don't use misleading or irrelevant titles like this.